# Eazfuscator.NET One or more errors occurred --> Index was out of range

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, obfuscation, eazfuscator

I'm using Eazfuscator 3.3 (Free version), and I **can** obfuscate all of my projects **except one** (in a specific solution).

this is the error I'm getting:

> Error    16    Error occurred during processing of input file
>   'DAL.dll' --> One or more errors occurred --> Index was out of range.
>   Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   C:\Projects__**_**_**__***DAL\EXEC*    ___DAL

i've tried to run this manually:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Eazfuscator.NET\Eazfuscator.NET.exe "C:\Projects\________\______DAL\bin\Release\______DAL.dll" --msbuild-project-path "C:\Projects\______\______DAL\______DAL.csproj" --msbuild-project-configuration "Release" --msbuild-project-platform "AnyCPU" --msbuild-solution-path "C:\Projects\______\______.sln" -n --newline-flush -v 3.3"
```

but i got the same result.

I even tried this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Eazfuscator.NET>Eazfuscator.NET.exe "C:\Projects\_______\_______DAL\bin\Release\________DAL.dll"
```

but, as you can see - i got the same result:

> Eazfuscator.NET  Version 3.3 (Release build 3.3.161.40493) Copyright
>   (C) 2007-2012 Oleksiy Gapotchenko
>
> Obfuscating assembly '***_*__***DAL.dll'...Error: Error occurred
>   during processing of input file ''*_____DAL.dll' --> One or more
>   errors occurred --> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and
>   less than the size of the collection.

I have a feeling that it happening  because of my references - *FluentNHibernate.dll* (1.2.0.712), *NHibernate.dll* (3.1.0.4000), *NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll* (3.1.0.4000).

Comment: More like Hardfuscator.NET, amirite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue and it was fixed in recent versions of Eazfuscator.NET.

**There is a quick workaround:**

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "optimization", Exclude = true)]
```

Please apply the attribute shown above to concerning assembly. This turns Eazfuscator.NET optimizer off.